# Mac - new terminal takes an unexpectedly large amount of time to open

Tags: bash, mac, terminal, zsh

I have observed lately that my bash takes a large amount of time to open. It seems it is running some commands in the background. I am using *Oh My ZSH* framework for the terminal. On the new terminal window tab, I can see the python command being run. [Check the screenshot!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZolSD.jpg)

I believe I may have mistakenly added that command (i.e., `python -c import keras`) in the `.profile` or `.zsh` file but I check in there and couldn't find anything. I even checked in the `/etc` folder for any clue but in vain.

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Not sure if this is the case here but I had a terminal take a long time to start because its prompt string invoked rather slow commands (in my case it tried to display the current git branch).

Comment: How do we get rid of this? What file do I edit? Or what did you do to get rid of it?

Comment: In Bash it is the PS1 environment variable.

Comment: Still, this proved to be of no help! I couldn't find anything useful in `PS1`. All that I could understand is that it is used to change the look and feel of the terminal and I've only a couple of things in it! However, thanks for the help @xenoid

Comment: First, I would check without oh-my-zsh, and then enable one plugin after another.

Answer (score 0):

Use grep to find where the command is at: Open a command prompt and type this command:

```
grep "import keras" *
```

The command prompt should default to your home directory, and those settings don't live in subdirectories, so that simple command is all you need.